# Login redirection not working with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I'm working on an app with login and private routes, so far I have done the login and declared the private routes like this...

```
        <Route path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/app" />} />
        <PrivateRoutes path="/app">
          <AdminLayout>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/app" exact render={() => <Redirect to="/app/dashboard" />} />
              <Route path="/app/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            </Switch>
          </AdminLayout>
        </PrivateRoutes>
        <HomeLayout>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/login" component={LogInPage} />
          </Switch>
        </HomeLayout>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

then i create my private routes:

```
!!isAuthenticated ? (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => children} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: '/login',
        state: { from: history.location },
      }}
    />
  );
```

finally, i redirect to app/dashboard

```
if (isLogged) {
    return <Redirect to="/app/dashboard" />;
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

so what is happening login works ok, it changes the URL but I don't see the components of the private route, I debugged it and it never declares these routes, if I keep the token and refresh I'm redirected as intended.
On the other hand a side question, im using hooks, how can I see that  `state: { from: history.location },` on the login component?

Comment: Does your router component, or `PrivateRotes` component react to the auth state being updated? Or in other words, have you determined if `isAuthenticated` updates in the component(s) when you expect it to? You can access route state from the `location` route prop.

Comment: ha! what a silly error, no private routes was not reacting because I was reading the token inside a useEffect I will update the post. for the other question I was asking how to get this state: { from: history.location } the state variable on an old class component it would be accessible from this.props but here i don't seem to find it, i need to know the route i came from so when i login i cant redirect to the path it came.

Comment: What and where are the components that are trying to access route props? Can you provide an example of where they are in relation to the `Router`? Is it the `LogInPage` component?

Comment: Yes is the login page component i have access to useHistory()

Comment: Use the `useLocation` hook, it'll be something like `const { state: { from } } = useLocation();`.

Comment: Instead of editing the question to include the answer from a comment, please add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). The benefits of this are that future visitors to the site can see that the question has an answer from other pages, and that the proposed answer may be one among others that might come along in the future and is subject to the up/down voting system.

Answer (score 0):

As Drew Reese commented my component was not updating this is why:

```
const PrivateRoutes = ({ children, ...rest }: Props) => {
  useInjectReducer({ key: sliceKey, reducer: reducer });
  useInjectSaga({ key: sliceKey, saga: authSaga });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const isAuthentificating = useSelector(selectIsAuthentificating);
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(selectIsAuthenticated);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token: string = cookies.get('token') || '';
    dispatch(actions.getAccountRequest({ token }));
    return () => {
      dispatch(actions.reset());
    };
  }, [dispatch]);
  
  return isAuthentificating ? (
```

I was getting the token inside the effect and that never happened I took it outside and it worked perfectly

For the other issue the state objected sended in the redirect is in the `useLocation()` hook